# Three.js texture mapping mode for base color

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I'm trying to apply an equirectangular reflection map to the .map field of a MeshBasicMaterial, to save performance vs rendering an entire MeshStandardMaterial just for the envMap.

Per [three's texture constants page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Textures), I thought I could achieve this by manually setting the texture's mapping to THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping before I assign the texture to material.map. This doesn't work though, the image is still mapped to UVs instead of as a reflection map.

How can I force the texture to follow the mapping I set?

Example code:

```
var myGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
var myTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('myEquirec.png');
myTexture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
var myMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: myTexture});
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(myGeo, myMaterial);
scene.add(myMesh);
```

I would expect this to be possible, otherwise why does Three let us set the mapping modes?

Comment: The sampling of the map must be based on the angle of incidence so the shader code must be different. For textures the UV coordinate is used. I'm afraid you'll have to make a custom shader to do what you're suggesting. You can see here that it looks like `mapping` is just used for environment maps. Maybe a documentation update is needed: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a37ada09b27b478733c39c3ef600f071d4a1e78a/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L273